# Get xml from mixed string in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I got string, that contains usual characters and xml. Like this

```
General Information
********************************************* bla-bla-bla

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><eventData><field key="SomeID">49ddd6f1-2fef-4cac-9eea-92df285370e7</field> <MyData>SomeData</MyData> </eventData>
```

How can get string, that contains only xml? Or even all after `<?xml` ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Select-String` and regular expressions. This returns everything including and after `<?xml`:

```
$s = @"
General Information
********************************************* bla-bla-bla

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><eventData>
<field key="SomeID">49ddd6f1-2fef-4cac-9eea-92df285370e7</field>
<MyData>SomeData</MyData> </eventData>
"@

$s | Select-String -Pattern "(?s)<\?xml.*" | % { $_.Matches.Value }
```